# Sentimental Analysis of text

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I have a code for performing sentimental analysis using Naive Bayes.
I have three files where in

1. `classifier.py`--> there is a function of naive bayes classifier.
2. `preprocessor.py`-->there are some functions to tokenize and
   categorise negative and positive text
3. `main.py`--> to create a interface to show output.

When I try executing them,Sometimes it shows a weird output like negative o/p for positive statements and positive o/p for negative statements.
Here is my code.

---

classifier.py

```
import random
import preprocess
import nltk

def get_classifier():

    data = preprocess.get_data()
    random.shuffle(data)

    split = int(0.8 * len(data))

    train_set = data[:split]
    test_set =  data[split:]

    classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

    accuracy = nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
    print("Generated Classifier")
    print('-'*70)
    print("Accuracy: ", accuracy)
    return classifier
```

---

preprocess.py

```
import nltk.classify
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

stop_words = stopwords.words("english")

def create_word_features_pos(words):
    useful_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
    my_list = [({word: True}, 'positive') for word in useful_words]
    return my_list


def create_word_features_neg(words):
    useful_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
    my_list = [({word: True}, 'negative') for word in useful_words]
    return my_list


def create_word_features(words):
    useful_words = [word for word in words if word not in stopwords.words("english")]

    pos_txt = get_tokenized_file(u"positive-words.txt")
    neg_txt = get_tokenized_file(u"negative-words.txt")

    my_dict = dict([(word, True) for word in pos_txt if word in useful_words])
    my_dict1 = dict([(word, False) for word in neg_txt if word in useful_words])

    my_dict.update(my_dict1)


    return my_dict

def get_tokenized_file(file):
    return word_tokenize(open(file, 'r').read())

def get_data():
    print("Collecting Negative Words")
    neg_txt = get_tokenized_file(u"negative-words.txt")
    neg_features = create_word_features_neg(neg_txt)

    print("Collecting Positive Words")
    pos_txt = get_tokenized_file(u"positive-words.txt")
    pos_features = create_word_features_pos(pos_txt)
    return pos_features + neg_features

def process(data):
    return [word.lower() for word in word_tokenize(data)]
```

---

main.py

```
  from preprocess import create_word_features, create_word_features_neg
from preprocess import create_word_features_pos, process
from classifier import get_classifier
import nltk.classify
from tkinter import *


print("Designing UI")
root = Tk()
root.wm_title('Sentiment Analysis Application')

top_frame = Frame(root)
top_frame.pack()

bottom_frame = Frame(root)
bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

l1 = Label(top_frame, text='Enter a review:')
l1.pack(side=LEFT)

w = Text(top_frame, height=4 )
w.pack(side=LEFT)

print("UI COMPLETE")
clf = get_classifier()

def main_op():
    review_spirit = w.get('1.0',END)
    demo = process(review_spirit)

    demo1 = create_word_features(demo)
    demo2 = ('review is ' + clf.classify(demo1))
    l2 = Label(bottom_frame, text=demo2)
    l2.pack()

button = Button(bottom_frame, text='Analyse', command=main_op )
button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

---

I will run this code in Anaconda Spyder.
Please help me to sort out this code for exact output.
Thank you.

Comment: *Sometimes it shows a weird output like negative o/p for positive statements and positive o/p for negative statements*  What's the accuracy you are getting from this model?

Comment: Accuracy:  0.7019867549668874 @AkshayNevrekar

Comment: so your question is How to improve the accuracy of the model?

Comment: @sudheeshdhadala as you said yourself the acc is .70 which means 30 out of 100 sample will be predicted wrongly. Improving the acc should be your next step even then dont expect you model to be 100% correct.

Comment: Then how can I improve the accuracy of the model Sir...? @mujjiga

Comment: Then how can I improve the accuracy of the model Sir...? @AkshayNevrekar